# Should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion

I have marked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192103/final-edittext-input-new-edittextthis-not-working) question as duplicate of this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c).
But I was wondering if a more appropriate curse of action would be closing it.

The OP doesn't normally use Java, so I am guessing he just used code from internet without checking for what language it was.

Under that context the user doesn't really know about the final word, or Java, so it seems to me a localized issue and that is not likely to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think it's OK to leave this one open, and I'm not convinced it's a duplicate of the other question.

The reasons:

- The question is asking more along the lines of, "Why doesn't this code work?" They've provided a code sample that exhibits the behavior.
- The duplicate in question is asking what the equivalent to `final` is in C#, as a user wishes to make use of those properties.
- Absence of knowledge of the `final` keyword in C# is no reason to say that these two questions are the same.  The motivation for asking both of them is *entirely* different.

Comment: I marked it as duplicate when I thought the user knew what final was. Then I realized he had no idea. I think the guidelines have been updated, but in the past weren't questions closed when they didn't show effort from the OP side? Also I don't take any issue with the OP's question, I am asking to understand better how the flagging/closing works.

Comment: Well first, assume good faith.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "not showing effort", but for the most part, I feel like there was enough here to reasonably answer the question.  My advice for flagging/closing would be to take the question at face value; if at face value it needs to be flagged/closed, then do so.

Comment: Well he grabbed a java example and tried to run it as c#, then he had an error and then probably didn't try to find the solution by himself. But In any case I like your approach, at face value, in this case there are doubts, so let it be. Thanks!